# I am getting following error ---- Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.set(): 'currentCount' of component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

[image]

I am new in lightning can anybody guide to resolve this error.

Component code --

```
<!-- attributes -->
<aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>   
<aura:attribute name="totalNumberOfRows" type="Integer" default="0"/>    
<aura:attribute name="sortedBy" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="sortedDirection" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="defaultSortDirection" type="String"/>

<!-- handlers-->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.doInit }"/>

<article class="slds-card slds-card_boundary">
    <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
        <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
            <div class="slds-media__figure">
                <lightning:icon iconName="standard:file" alternativeText="File" size="small" />
            </div>
            <div class="slds-media__body">
                <h2 class="slds-card__header-title">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-card__header-link slds-truncate" title="{!'Attachments (' + v.totalNumberOfRows + ')'}">
                        <span class="slds-text-heading_small">{!'Attachments (' + v.totalNumberOfRows + ')'}</span>
                    </a>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!greaterthan(v.totalNumberOfRows, 0)}">
        <div class="slds-card__body slds-scrollable--y" id="attachment-table">
            <lightning:datatable columns="{! v.columns }"
                                 data="{! v.data }"
                                 keyField="id"
                                 rowNumberOffset="0"
                                 onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }"
                                 sortedBy="{! v.sortedBy }"
                                 sortedDirection="{! v.sortedDirection }"
                                 defaultSortDirection="{! v.defaultSortDirection }"
                                 onsort="{! c.updateColumnSorting }"
                                 hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
        </div>
    </aura:if>
</article>
```

Controller code ---

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

        var totalCnt = component.get("c.getTotalCount");
        totalCnt.setParams({
            "parentId": component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        totalCnt.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            component.set("v.totalNumberOfRows", a.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(totalCnt);       

        var actions = [
            { label: 'View', name: 'view' },
            { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' }
        ];

        component.set('v.columns', [
            { type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions } },
            {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text',sortable:true },
            {label: 'Owner', fieldName: 'OwnerName', type: 'text',sortable:true },
            {label: 'Last Modified', fieldName: 'LastModifiedDate', type: 'datetime',sortable:true }
        ]);
        helper.getData(component);
    },
    // Client-side controller called by the onsort event handler
    updateColumnSorting: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var fieldName = event.getParam('fieldName');
        var sortDirection = event.getParam('sortDirection');
        // assign the latest attribute with the sorted column fieldName and sorted direction
        cmp.set("v.sortedBy", fieldName);
        cmp.set("v.sortedDirection", sortDirection);
        helper.sortData(cmp, fieldName, sortDirection);
    },
    handleRowAction: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var action = event.getParam('action');
        var row = event.getParam('row');
        switch (action.name) {
            case 'view':
                var attId = row.Id;               
                var url = "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" + attId;
                window.open(url, '_blank');
                break;
            case 'delete':
                var rows = cmp.get('v.data');
                var rowIndex = rows.indexOf(row);
                var deleteAct = cmp.get("c.deleteAttachments");
                deleteAct.setParams({ ids : rows[rowIndex].Id });
                $A.enqueueAction(deleteAct);
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": "Success!",
                    "message": "The attachment has been delete successfully.",
                    "type": "success"
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
                rows.splice(rowIndex, 1);
                cmp.set('v.totalNumberOfRows', rows.length);
                cmp.set('v.data', rows);
                break;    
        }
    },
})
```

helper code---

```
({
    getData : function(component) {

        var action = component.get("c.getAttachmentList");
        action.setParams({
            "parentId": component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            var rows = a.getReturnValue();
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var row = rows[i];
                if (row.Owner.Name) row.OwnerName = row.Owner.Name;
                if(row.LastModifiedDate) row.LastModifiedDate = $A.localizationService.formatDate(row.LastModifiedDate, "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a");
            }
            component.set("v.data", rows);
            component.set("v.currentCount", component.get("v.initialRows"));

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    sortData: function (cmp, fieldName, sortDirection) {
        var data = cmp.get("v.data");
        var reverse = sortDirection !== 'asc';
        //sorts the rows based on the column header that's clicked
        data.sort(this.sortBy(fieldName, reverse))
        cmp.set("v.data", data);
    },
    sortBy: function (field, reverse, primer) {
        var key = primer ?
            function(x) {return primer(x[field])} :
        function(x) {return x[field]};
        //checks if the two rows should switch places
        reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;
        return function (a, b) {
            return a = key(a), b = key(b), reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
        }
    }

})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The getData() function in helper is trying to set value to a component attribute named **currentCount**, which is not available in the component markup. Since this attribute is executed in **doInit**, you are getting the error.

Comment: so what markupup i have to use or if i removed it than it effect the task ?

Comment: `component.set("v.currentCount", component.get("v.initialRows"));`
In the above line, both of the attributes are not defined within the component markup, why are u setting value from one attribute from another? Try commenting this line and see if it works.